# segmentation error in recursion with conditions

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

void verify(int a[],int,int);

int main()
{
    int a[SIZE],target,k=0;
    printf("enter the array elemans:\n");

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    printf("enter the target :\n");
    scanf("%d",&target);

    verify(a,target,k);
    return 0;
}

void verify(int a[],int target,int k)
{
    int count=0;
    if(a[k]==target&&count<SIZE)
    {
        printf("target found:%d at index= %d\n",a[k],k);
        verify(a,target,k+1);
        count+=1;
    }
    else if(count<SIZE)
    {
        verify(a,target,k+1);
        count+=1;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("target not found !!!");
    }
}
```

when i try to find a number not in the list/array i don't get the else statement execute but rather it displays segmentation error 11 pls find the mistake in my code

Comment: You need to learn how to use gdb for debugging your code.  use  `-g` flag when you compile your program with `GCC` and use then use gdb to know what is causing the segfault.

Comment: You test that `count` is not over `SIZE`, but you read the array with `k`...

Comment: Why are you calling `verify()` again with `k+1` when the target found?

Comment: Probably a stackoverflow, use your debugger.

Comment: Just printing out a dot, '.', at each call would give an idea of the depth.  Why have you not used even such primitive debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting segmentation fault because `count` is a local variable of `verify()` function and in every recursive call to `verify()` function, the `count` initializes to `0` and the condition `count<SIZE` will always be `true`.
In every recursive call to `verify()`, you are passing `k+1` and comparing the element at `k`th location of array `a` with the `target` --> `if(a[k]==target&&count<SIZE){....`. At one stage the `k` will be having a value which is beyond the size of the array `a`. Your program is accessing the element beyond the array size which is undefined behavior which includes program may give segmentation fault.

You dont need `count` variable at all. Just compare the value of `k` to with `SIZE` to ensure that it should not go beyond the array size.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some bound check on the array index. (Array access out of bound is undefined behavior) Here you have accessed array index out of bound.

First check if the access would be out of range - if that's the case you return from there, else you access it and check it. And then have the next recursive call.

```
if(k >= SIZE){
   printf("target not found !!!");
}
else{
   if(a[k] == target){
     ...
   }
   //next call
}
```

The `count` variable is not there when you return from the function. It is not needed or it's use not clear in this case.

The complete code can be as simple as this:

```
void verify(int a[],int target,int k)
{
    if(k < SIZE)
    {
        if(a[k] == target)
          printf("target found:%d at index= %d\n",a[k],k);
        else 
          verify(a,target,k+1);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("target not found !!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a[k]==target&&count<SIZE) and else if(count<SIZE)
```

are always true as count is always zero in each iteration of recursion, you should use `k` for instead of `count` in your conditions